# EF Core check if object in related table exists, if not - add it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have the following class:

```
public class Item
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }        

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ItemCategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

and an ItemCategory class:

```
public class ItemCategory
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want each item to have one category and a category to be able to have many items. I am using code first and so far everything looks good - using migrations EF created an "Items" and "ItemCategories" tables with the appropriate foreign keys ("Items" table has a column "CategoryID" that references the "ID" column of the "ItemCategories" table). My problem is that if I have a category of, say, "Book" with ID 1 and I add a new Item with category "Book" in the "ItemCategories" a second entry is inserted that has ID 2 and name "Book". I want to change this behaviour to the following:

When a new Item is added, check if its Category.Name already exists in "ItemCategories". If it does set the "CategoryID" to its ID. If it does not - add a new record to "ItemCategories" and set "CategoryID" to its ID.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a function that gets or creates the unique ItemCategory. You did not post the full code so I am not sure how your repository looks like. But here is an idea:

```
    // assuming _dbServices is the injected dbcontext
    public void AddItem()
    {
        var item = _dbServices.Context.Entry(new Item()
        {
            Name = "First book",
            Category = GetOrCreateItemCategory(new ItemCategory() { Name = "Book" })
        }).State = EntityState.Added;
        _dbServices.Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public ItemCategory GetOrCreateItemCategory(ItemCategory category)
    {
        var findCategory = _dbServices.Context.Set<ItemCategory>().Where(x => x.ID == category.ID).FirstOrDefault();
        if (findCategory == null)
        {
            _dbServices.Context.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Added;
            _dbServices.Context.SaveChanges();
            return category;
        }
        return findCategory;
    }
```

I havent tested this but should be ok. If not, please comment and I would fix it.
Also I would create unique index for ItemCategory.Name field.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ItemCategory>()
        .HasIndex(p => new { p.Name })
        .IsUnique(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define foreign key property  in the dependent entity class And when you add a new item, set the CategoryID instead of Category .

```
public class Item
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }        

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }   


    public ItemCategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a navigation property in the Item class.

```
public class ItemCategory
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set;}

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{        
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; } // Primary Key

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ItemCategory ItemCategory { get; set; } //Navigation Property
}
```